# how to use CloudFront without alternate domain name

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I created a CloudFront Distribution which has a publicly accessible S3 bucket as origin. The problem is that I always get below 403 error when I try to get the object using the `Distribution domain name` eg. `https://*****.cloudfront.cn/sand/webpack/runtime.8d81c17e3553679ae349.js`.

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
```

However, it works fine if i set the `alternative domain name` for my distribution. I can successfully access `https://my.domain.com/sand/webpack/runtime.8d81c17e3553679ae349.js`

The aws documents show that `Distribution domain name` works, it does not mention that `alternative domain name` must be set to make the distribution work.

We DO NOT want to use the `alternative domain name` to access our objects. We want to use the `Distribution domain name` directly.

Please advise how we can CloudFront without alternate domain name? and kindly advise if we missed any configuration.

Comment: I don't think this should be an issue. I have a website that works with both domains.

Comment: `https://*****.cloudfront.cn`, why is there `.cn`, it should be `.net`.

Comment: This the distribution name for China region. Distribution domain name is not working in China region

Answer (score 0):

I was told by aws that `alternative domain name` is required in China region.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).